$f = 0$ a.e. on every $\omega_i$ for $i \in I$ then $f = 0$ a.e. might not hold on $\cup \omega_i$ if $I$ is not countable
This question comes from the proof of Proposition 4.17 (definition of support for a function) in Brezis's Function Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations.
We want to prove that

On $\mathbb{R}^N$ (with the usual topology), if $f=0$ a.e. on every $\omega_i$ where $i \in I$ and $\omega_i$ is open, then $f = 0$ a.e. on $\cup_{i\in I} \omega_i$.

By the book, this is not immediate because $I$ might not be countable.
The result is obvious if $I$ is finite or countable, but why the proposition above is not generally true if $I$ is not countable? Is there some examples?

"Not immediate" means it requires proof, not that it can be false.  In this case, do you know something about the topology on $\mathbb{R}^N$ that lets you assume $I$ is countable?  (Maybe using a more basic set replacing the $\omega_i$?)

Yes we can. Because $\mathbb{R}^N$ has a countable open basis, there is a countable collection of open sets that can express all the open sets on $\mathbb{R}^N$. And eventually $\cup_{i \in I} \omega_i$ is no more than doing the union in that countable collection of open sets. But I am curious about why we cant deduce $f=0$ a.e. on the union of $\omega_i$'s if $I$ is not countable, although this can be resolved in the case of $\mathrm{R}^N$. @Brian Moehring

In that case, you may want to qualify your question some.  If we don't consider the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^N$, then there are easy [possibly trivial] counterexamples (e.g. lebesgue measure, but with sets open in the discrete topology)

Thank you very much. I think I see it, and will try to post a counter example below. @Brian Moehring

A counter-example (that I assume is appropriate) may be counstrcuted by choosing a different topology on $\mathbb{R}$, as suggested in the comments.
Consider the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. We write
$$
[0, 1] = \left( \cup_n \{r_n, e_n\} \right) \cup \left(\cup_i \{ e_i, r_1 \} \right),
$$
where $r_n$ are rational numbers in $[0, 1]$ and $e_i$ are irrational numbers in $[0, 1]$, and in $\{r_n, e_n\}$ we take some $e_i$ and denote it by $e_n$ for each $n$. Here $(e_i)$ is of course a uncountable set.
We then let $f = 0$ on each $r_n$, and $f=1$ on each $e_i$, thus getting $f=0$ a.e. on each open set $\{r_n, e_n\}$ or $\{r_n, e_n\}$ (since we use the discrete topology), but $f = 1$ a.e. on $[0, 1]$.
